# Calling a Promise function inside Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to issue an HTTP request to another web service, from a Google Cloud Function (GCF) that I have created. I need the HTTP request to complete and return that result inside of my GCF so that I can do something else with it.

My question is; What is the best way to use Promise inside a Google Cloud Function? Is what I am trying to do possible?

My code currently looks like this:

```
export const MyGCF = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  let dayOfTheWeek: any;

  const request1 = require('request');
  const url = 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/pst/now';
  function getDay() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request1(url, { json: true }, (err: any, res: any, body: any) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(body.dayOfTheWeek);
        });
    });
  }

  getDay().then((data) => {
      dayOfTheWeek = data;
      console.log(dayOfTheWeek);
  });

});
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can write arbitrary code inside your function.  But you're never actually sending a response back to the client with `response.send()` or anything equivalent, so this function will always just time out.

Comment: Thanks Doug.. could I get a code example. I am confused on how to write one.

Comment: "*I am not sure if I could have multiple functions inside a google cloud function.*" - yes you can

Comment: If you're confused about how to write code for Cloud Functions, you should start with the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: I know how to write code for cloud function but I do not know how to write promise function call inside a CF. I  could not find code example and in my code editor I get errors. so I am looking for simple example

Comment: You generally don't need to use new promises.  It's easier to use an HTTP library that deals in promises rather than trying to make its callbacks use a different promise.  Try using the request-promise module instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general your approach will work, and you can define additional functions inside of your `MyGCF` handler, in the same way that you have defined `getDay()`. One problem with you current code however is that you're forgetting to "write a response" for the request being processed by `MyGCF`.

You can write a response for the request by calling `send()` on the second `res` argument of your `MyGCF` request handler. A simple example would be:

```
/* Sends a response of "hello" for the request */
res.send("hello");
```

With respect to your code, you can use `res.send()` in your `.then()` callback to send a response back to the client after `getDay()` has completed (see code below). Note also to include a `.catch()` clause and callback for the error case (with an error status) to ensure the client receives an appropriate error response if the call to `getDay()` fails:

```js
export const MyGCF = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const request = require('request');
  const url = 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/pst/now';

  function getDay() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(url, {
        json: true
      }, (err: any, r: any, body: any) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(body.dayOfTheWeek);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  getDay().then((dayOfTheWeek) => {
      /* Send a response once the getDay() request complete */
      res.send(dayOfTheWeek);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      /* Don't forget the error case */
      res.status(500).send(err);
    });

});
```